# Invoke Python SimpleHTTPServer from command line with no cache option

Tags: python

On Windows 7, I am using the command line

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

to invoke a simple web server to serve files from a directory, for development.

The problem is that the server seems to keep the files in cache. Old versions of files are served despite newer ones being available.

Is there a way to specify the "no cache" option from the command line directly?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+F5 in your browser for refresh, instead of F5?

Comment: I made a modern Python 3 version of the highest voted answer: https://gist.github.com/opyate/6e5fcabc6f41474d248613c027373856

Comment: What helped in my case (Firefox) was to open the developer console and tick "Disable cache" in the network tab. Ctrl+F5 did not help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest that you press Ctrl+F5 when refreshing the browser.

Just ran into [this](https://gist.github.com/3300372), it can just might be the thing you are looking for (it's in ruby, by the way)

Comment: But but but, I'm using jQuery AJAX. Even setting ` $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Some people are debugging in Safari on their iPhone. No CTRL+F5 equivalent there.

Answer (score 55):

Perhaps this may work. Save the following to a file:

**serveit.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def send_my_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        self.send_header("Pragma", "no-cache")
        self.send_header("Expires", "0")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass=MyHTTPRequestHandler)
```

then run it using

```
python serveit.py 8000
```

to serve the current directory on port 8000. This was totally pulled [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/dustingetz/5348582), and seems to work great!

NOTE: If you're just looking to run a local webserver to serve static content, you may be interested in a [precanned node solution to do this => http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server), which I've been using and seems to work great.

Also if you're on a mac, if you run this as root you can run it on port 80 or 443! For example

`sudo python serveit.py 80`

should allow you to run it and access it in your browser at `http://localhost`

Comment: Adding this to `.bash_profile` makes it more convenient to use:

`alias server="open http://localhost:8000/ && echo 'Starting server at localhost:8000' && python ~/serveit.py 8000 > /dev/null 2>&1"`

Comment: A theory why this works: SimpleHTTPRequestHandler only sends `Last-Modified` header; it doesn't send max-age or any explicit info how long its valid but browsers cache by default for some heuristic time:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496694/whats-default-value-of-cache-control, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852117/239657, unless explicitly told not to (which "Cache-Control" here does).

Comment: Modernised for Python 3 -> https://gist.github.com/opyate/6e5fcabc6f41474d248613c027373856

Comment: Almost, but you really have got to call the super methods.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 36):

Of course the script above will not work for Python 3.x, but it just consists of changing the `SimpleHTTPServer` to `http.server` as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import http.server

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_my_headers()
        http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)

    def send_my_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        self.send_header("Pragma", "no-cache")
        self.send_header("Expires", "0")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    http.server.test(HandlerClass=MyHTTPRequestHandler)
```

Comment: Almost, but you really have got to call the super methods.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's the browser caching your files not the SimpleHTTPServer. Try deactivating the browser cache first.

Comment: I figured out this is the case for me, by trying load the page from Firefox instead of Chrome. However, how do I fix this on chrome?

Comment: This works for me in Firefox: Empty Browser Cache in Firefox (versions 4 to 67): Press the keys Ctrl + Shift + Del. A new window will open. Activate the option "Cache" and then click on "Delete now"

Answer (score 2):

I changed to another port number and the updated file reflected on my browser.

ex.

```py
python -m http.server -p 8000

python -m http.server -p 8001
```