# Browser behavior when no cache-control policy header defined

Tags: caching, browser, http-headers, cache-control

I'm trying to improve the caching policy for a web site.

I'm implementing an aggressive caching strategy first, for resources that won't change at all, and would like files like jquery-min for example to be downloaded only once, and then be served from browser cache.

I used Apache Mod-Expire module to accomplish this, and it's working pretty well.

However, I'm surprised that when I completely remove my cache-control configuration, Firefox  browser does not re-download jquery file : it already gets it from the cache, without any instruction from me. How is Firefox making this kind of decision ? Is it related to the ETag hash ?

Here are the headers I get without my configuration for that particular file :

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection      Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  27073
Content-Type    application/javascript
Date    Fri, 23 Aug 2013 09:48:06 GMT
Etag    "225f8-13309-4e385823c7b80"
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=99
Last-Modified   Fri, 09 Aug 2013 15:34:22 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the browser behavior when there's no Cache-Control policy defined ? is it browser dependant ?

Thank you,

Mathieu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What heuristics do browsers use to cache resources not explicitly set to be cachable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345898/what-heuristics-do-browsers-use-to-cache-resources-not-explicitly-set-to-be-cach)