# Why directive templates sometimes are loaded from server (with 304 response) and sometimes from browser cache (no request at all)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, browser-cache

When I reload page, Angular directive templates are loaded in two ways.
First one - browser makes a request to the server and it responses with 304 - it's ok.
[image: When loading from jQuery.ready]

But the second one - browser **doesn't make a request**. And I can't guess why.
[image: When loading from within Angular]

As a result, when I make changes in templates from the first group, the changes are shown with the next page reload. But the changes in templates from the second group are not shown. That's the trouble.

And the question is - how to make the browser send request to the server for each template?

Comment: Please provide response headers for templates in both cases.

Comment: @miensol, when first request, cache is clear, response is http://i.imgur.com/3hV9lwu.jpg. When 304, response is http://i.imgur.com/6BusLkx.jpg. When request isn't sent and cache data is used, it looks http://i.imgur.com/fBoE3aD.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the response headers for templates there are no [`Cache-Control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) headers. In such case [a browser will use a heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345898/what-heuristics-do-browsers-use-to-cache-resources-not-explicitly-set-to-be-cach) to decide for how long a response **can** be cached.

To solve your problem of having always fresh templates fetched in development. You can:

- check "Disable cache" in developer tools
- set a proper `Cache-Control` header for resources you care about i.e :

  `Cache-Control: no-cache`

If you want to understand different behaviours triggered by various `Cache-Control` values I highly recommend [this article by Ilya Grigorik](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).

Comment: Thx, @miensol, when setting Cache-Control to max-age=0, browser sends a request on every reload and server returns 304. But when setting to max-age=10 it works wierd: files from the second group are cached for 10 seconds as expected, but the queries from the first group are required from the server with 304 response. Both groups are with Cache-Control & Expires headers.  Looks like Chrome uses a heuristic for the first group inspite of Cache-Control headers. Do you know why?

Comment: Well if I read http specs correctly setting `max-age=10` tells the client (browser in our case) that it's ok to cache the content for at most 10 seconds. In other words it's not saying that the client should not contact the server during that period.

Comment: So, it's the browser to decide to follow the max-age=10 attribute or not? Ok, thx!

Comment: The browser must take max-age=10 into account, but it's up to it decide whether to go to server or not.