# How long will cached CSS file get updated in browser?

Tags: css, http, browser

How long will cached CSS file get updated in browser if I don't do anything specifically?

I googled this but haven't found a clear answer. I know I can use `file.css?v=1` to force the browser to load the updated version or I can use hard reload feature of the browser. But what if I don't do all of these? So far the browser will always load the cached old version.

Without hard reload and any other setup in server, how long will a local browser update the cached CSS file? Will the cached version stay there forever? *(unless the cache space is full to make space)*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's default value of cache-control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496694/whats-default-value-of-cache-control)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks a lot for the quick reply. I think it's related, but not duplicated. That question's focus is the value of cache-control. My focus is the browser's behavior. I think a browser does not have to follow cache-control. Chrome, Safari, IE/edge, firefox or opera may have different decision on how to handle cached css file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers generally follow the [IETF spec for HTTP caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2%5D). This was introduced in the HTTP 1.1 spec. But they do all vary if the content being served doesn't use an HTTP Cache-Control header. Ultimately you can't rely on the hope that your updated file will be loaded by the client unless you either use a URL cache-buster, as you mentioned, or serve your content with proper cache-control headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I really want to know what browsers do these days. For example, how long will chrome browser to update its cache? Will it keep the old cached file forever? or 2 days, 3 days or more? Thanks a lot.